# How to combine stepped frequency and phase coding waveforms in matlab?

Tags: matlab, waveform, pulse, tx

I'm working on a radar project, I want to combine Stepped frequency and Phase coding (SFPC). I need some help how to combine them.

```
waveform = phased.SteppedFMWaveform('SampleRate',50e6,...
'PulseWidth',0.04e-6,'PRF',100e3,...
'NumSteps',5,'NumPulses',5);

sPCW = phased.PhaseCodedWaveform('SampleRate',50e6,'Code','Barker',...
'ChipWidth',0.04e-6,'NumChips',13,'PRF',100e3,...
'OutputFormat','Pulses','NumPulses',5);
```

These are the two waveforms. Any idea how to combine them?
Thank You